# how to change titles and add captions in tidyverse

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

My code produces the following picture:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(pwt10)

pwt10.0 %>% 
  filter(isocode == "KOR") %>% 
    select(year, rgdpe,avh,rconna,rtfpna,rkna) %>% 
    tidyr::gather(predictor, value, -year) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(year, value))+
    geom_line()+
        facet_wrap(~predictor, scales = "free")
```

[image]

1. I want to change each title like avh to AVH, rconna to RCON,...etc.
2. Also add `year` caption below x-axis and `unit` caption for y-axis below every five graph.
3. finally add the caption written as `data source: World Bank` below the entire graph.
4. I want to remove gray color of background of both banner and body.

Comment: Although these are all pretty minor fixes to make, it's better to focus on one question per post. I'd also recommend looking at the ggplot docs first, as well as the tutorials they link to, to learn about setting theme options and labels, then come back here when you hit a roadblock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rename()` from dplyr or just simply assign to object and use `toupper()` function to convert data like i did below.

> ```
> df = pwt10.0 %>%
>   filter(isocode == "KOR") %>%
>   select(year, rgdpe,avh,rconna,rtfpna,rkna) %>%
>   tidyr::gather(predictor, value, -year)
> df$predictor = toupper(df$predictor)
> ```

After some reasearch i found that facet_wrap do not provide simple solution for this. Good alternative for printing subplots is using `grid.arrange()` from `library(grid)` and`library(gridExtra)`.

Use for loop to assign multiple figures to object at once.

```
for(i in c("AVH","RCONNA","RGDPE","RKNA","RTFPNA")){
assign(x = i,value = ggplot(df[df$predictor == i,],aes(year, value)) + 
geom_line()+ theme_classic() + theme(strip.background = element_blank())) + 
xlab("Year") + ylab("Value")}
```

`xlab("Year") + ylab("Value")` Sets names for x and y axis

`theme_classic() + theme(strip.background = element_blank()))` Removes background as specified.

Final plot function with `grid.arrange()`

> ```
> grid.arrange(
> AVH,    RCONNA,    RGDPE,    RKNA,    RTFPNA,
> nrow = 2,
> top = "Title of the Chart",
> bottom = textGrob(
> "Data source: World Bank",
> gp = gpar(fontface = 3, fontsize = 9),
> hjust = 1,x = 1))
> ```

[image: Subplot]